# How to imbed "notion" page to TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

There are plugins available for embedding posts from Instagram, Twitter but I am wondering how to go about embedding page from **Notion** to the text editor? It might also require **OAuth** for user authentication. How would you guys build the functionality like this to enhance the text editor(plugged in from TinyMCE).

As shown below in the picture, this is a form for user to write the book summary and share with others. I want to add a button by which the user
can directly pull the page content from **notion** to text editor. I've
checked the documentation of notion API and the page will be **redirected** after **OAuth** and it doesn't seem possible to inject the fetched data to the same ejs file.
[image]